# Hiding select option based on value that i choose

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm having a simple code like this

```html
<div class="form-group form-material floating">
    <select class="form-control" name="first" id="first">
        <option value="opt1">First Option</option>
        <option value="opt2">Second Option</option>
    </select>
    <label class="floating-label" for="inputStatus">Option</label>
</div>
```

and

```html
<div class="form-group form-material floating">
    <select class="form-control" name="second" id="second">
        <option value="val1">First Value</option>
        <option value="val2">Second Value</option>
        <option value="val3">Third Value</option>
        <option value="val4">Fourth Value</option>
    </select>
    <label class="floating-label" for="inputStatus">Option</label>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is when i choose 'opt1' i want the other select only show 'val2, val3, val4' and if i choose 'opt2' i want the other select only show 'val1, val2, val4' .. how do i do that ?

Comment: you are not using jquery for it ?

Comment: Did you try anything to achieve this?

Comment: yes .. i'm trying using a javascript for that .. but all the value is either gone .. or nothing changed .. so that's why i'm asking here @Rob

Comment: I can't see that this really has anything to do with Laravel - this is all clientside javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#first").on('change', function(){

if(this.value == 'opt1')
{
$(".op3").removeClass("hidden");
$(".op1").addClass("hidden");
}
else if(this.value == 'opt2')
{
$(".op1").removeClass("hidden");
$(".op3").addClass("hidden");
}
  
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none !important;}
```

```html
<div class="form-group form-material floating">
            <select class="form-control" name="first" id="first">
                <option value="opt1">First Option</option>
                <option value="opt2">Second Option</option>
            </select>
            <label class="floating-label" for="inputStatus">Option</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-material floating">
            <select class="form-control" name="second" id="second">
                <option class="op1" value="val1">First Value</option>
                <option value="val2">Second Value</option>
                <option class="op3" value="val3">Third Value</option>
                <option value="val4">Fourth Value</option>
            </select>
            <label class="floating-label" for="inputStatus">Option</label>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```